# Show a Blank Page on Back Pressed Button

Tags: android

When I press the back button to come back from a fragment, my activity shows a blank page.
What can I do to show the previous state of activity?
I use back stack in my project.
This is my code for pressing the back button:

```
public void onBackPressed() 
{ 
  if ( manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) 
  { 
    manager.popBackStack(); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    super.onBackPressed(); 
  } 
} 
});
```

and this is for the fragment:

```
public void addFragmentA() 
{ 
  FragmentA a = new FragmentA();  
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, a,"fraga").addToBackStack("fraga").commit(); 
}
```

The code for the listener is:

```
manager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
```

I want to work with a listener.
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show code where you are pressing back button

Comment: @zahra_s  in fragments onBackPressed() do not works

Comment: @AliAhmed i implements onbackstackchangeslistener

Comment: show code for listener.

Comment: @AliAhmed          manager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

Comment: I think so, my answer will work for your problem. Or you want to do your work with Listener ? Should i post answer **How to use listener?** with proper example.

Comment: @AliAhmed I want to work with Listener

Answer (score 0):

You can use your **Fragments View** to move to any other Fragment or Activity.

In your **Fragment.xml -> onCreateView()** method

```
    view.requestFocus();
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //Write you code here to go back to any activity or fragment
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```